# Streamlink how to seek to X minutes while downloading

Tags: streamlink

I am using Streamlink to download videos from streams and process. I wonder is streamlink has API to seek to X minutes before starting downloading when using with option "-o"

example:  (just assuming --seek option, this is not a valid one)

```
streamlink -o output_video.ts "https://mystreamurl.opencv.co" best --seek 120
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's an HLS stream, you can use the [--hls-start-offset](https://streamlink.github.io/cli.html#cmdoption-hls-start-offset) option. For example:

```
streamlink https://raw.githubusercontent.com/noamtamim/hls-bunny/master/index.m3u8 180k --hls-start-offset 2m
```

will start approximately 2 minutes in to the stream.